# Discover how Go was installed

Tags: apt, software-installation, log, binary, golang

Is it possible to discover how the latest version of `go` was installed on my Ubuntu 22.04 system?

I think it was installed in 2 different ways, thinking of updating it in a consistent way so theres no multiple copies of go all over the system.

```
$ go version
go version go1.18.4 linux/amd64

$ which go
/home/gameveloster/.go/bin/go

$ ll ~/.go/bin/go
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gameveloster gameveloster 14542735 Jul 12 11:25 /home/gameveloster/.go/bin/go*

$ ll /usr/local/go/bin/go
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14542442 May 10  2022 /usr/local/go/bin/go*

$ /usr/local/go/bin/go version
go version go1.18.2 linux/amd64
```

Tried grepping the two log files but cant locate go package in them, so it was probably not using `apt`.

```
$ cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep go   # matched only google-chrome-stable:amd64
$ cat /var/log/apt/term.log | grep go      # matched only google-chrome-stable:amd64
```

Comment: Apt doesn't install anything in `/usr/local` or in your home directory. Those were installed by you or your system's administrator by some other way.

Comment: take note that you must first remove all golang installs prior to installing go on a box